# swift 3 Type 'Any' error

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3, xcode8

So I had a perfectly working project using swift 2. Then I updated xcode and it converted the code to Swift 3. Now im getting this error every time I call snapshot. I'm using Firebase as my backend. This is my code.

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth


struct User {

var username: String!
var email: String!
var photoUrl: String!
var country: String!
var ref: FIRDatabaseReference?
var key: String!


init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot){

    key = snapshot.key
    username = snapshot.value!["username"] as! String
    email = snapshot.value!["email"] as! String
    photoUrl = snapshot.value!["photoUrl"] as! String
    country = snapshot.value!["country"] as! String
    ref = snapshot.ref

}




}
```

I'm getting the error that reads: Type 'Any' has no subscript members. This error is on the lines that have snapshot.value in them. Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about something like:

```
let values = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String,String>
username = values["username"]
...
```

Comment: This seems to have fixed the error! I had to start a new project because the other one got really messed up but Ill let you know if it wokrs when i get to that point again! thank you.

Comment: it's answer in this case, but value - not always String. It could be NSNumber or NSDictionary.

Answer (score 1):

before Xcode 8 beta 6 snapshot.values was of type [String:AnyObject]. Just cast it

```
guard snapshot.exists() else { return }
let value = snapshot.value as! [String:AnyObject]
username = value["username"] as! String
```

Answer (score 0):

The snapshot.value can be a Dictionary, Array, String, etc. Also, in Swift 3 there was a change to how to represent a Dictionary. It went from `[String:AnyObject]` to [`String:Any]`.

The right way to do this is to make sure to safely unwrap all values like this:

```
// swift 3    
if let userDict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
    username = userDict["username"] as? String
}
```